# Workbench 6.3 on Windows 10

Tags: mysql-workbench, configuration-files, mysql-error-2006

I have a problem with `Workbench 6.3` on my Win 10 machine. When I open WB and run a query after idle for about a minute, I get an error:

> Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away
>   Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I have set DBMS connection keep-alive interval, read time out and connection time out to 3600 seconds, but the problem still persists.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you file a bug report (http://bugs.mysql.com), so this gets solved properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is Workbench 6.3.6 issue. Once I downgraded to 6.3.4 everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the packet size 
contents of /etc/my.cnf that corrected this issue for me below:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet= 64M
wait_timeout= 6000
```

There is also another Q&A for your error code here: [Getting MYSQL Error: "Error Code: 2006 - MySQL server has gone away"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054832/getting-mysql-error-error-code-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: This is not a server issue, but rather a Workbench issue. I am connecting to Bluehost public hosting MySQL server so I am not able to change any server settings. And everything was working just fine in my previous Workbench version running on Win 8.1.